# How would you render a line superimposed by text in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to do something like this in my design and I'm not sure how I should do it:

[image: Example]

Comment: http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm

Comment: Two divs, one of which is floated right inside another one, the inner one having 100px of right margin. The outer one has a bottom border and the inner one is positioned relative and is pushed down 10px to cross the border.

Comment: By the way OP, we _really_ like to see prior effort here. The community seems to have sprung into action to suggest approaches, which surprises me: I imagined this would earn you a torrent of downvotes. Thus, if you can give it a go first, that makes for a better question: you can present a non-working attempt and people can show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Though this can be accomplished with pseudo elements, likely the most 'hassle free way' would be to wrap a `span` with a `div`, using for example the code below:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/P6yL5/)

*nb, a demo for off-centre alignment for the text can be seen [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/P6yL5/1/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>text text text</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background:black;
}
div {
    border-bottom:4px solid grey;
    height:.5em;
    text-align:center;
}
span {
    color:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:black;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

---

Note, that semantically it is perhaps more appropriate to [use `hr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) instead of `div`, however `div` has been used above due to the fact `hr` is often associated with more styles 'out of the box' which would need to be overridden- thereby adding to the required amount of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

[click for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3L3ub/1/)

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="line">

</div>   
  <div id="text">
      <span> text</span>
      <span> text</span>
      <span> text</span>
</div>  


</div>
```

### Css

```
#container
{

    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#line{

    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:orange;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:35px;
}
#text{

    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    color:greem;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    top:30px;
    left:500px;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: unnecessary use of position absolute.

Comment: what is your other suggestion